# Div container still keeps sized of original image size when transform is used

Tags: html, css, transform

I have The following code:

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
   <img src="http://imgurl" style="transform: scale(0.5);"/>
   <div>img name</div>
</div>
```

problem is that original img size is 510x255px;

After transform image is resized but div keeps still 510x255.

How to make it resized?

Thanks,

Comment: transform is only visual effect doesn't affect real size (height/width) --> consider changing height/width if you want this effect

Comment: Add your `transform: scale(0.5);` to the div also ?

Comment: Yeah but i want it dynamically. I mean like "percentage wise"

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa no. It will resize image then too i guess

Comment: You are executing the transform in CSS which like @TemaniAfif mentioned doesn't resize height/width. Because it's CSS it loads after the div has been created meaning the div wont resize because it's been told the size it should be before the image has then been told to resize. Perhaps doing this with JS could resize the div?

Comment: Add `transform` effect to the div only. then give `height: 100%` to the image

Comment: width & height in % is "percentage wise"

Comment: If you're also looking for dynamic sizing for height/width you can use height: 50% or width 50%. It works as well.

Comment: @VXp not for imgs

Comment: @Abinthaha Well this pretty helped. But it resized also "img name" :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your image is defined with fixed height/width you can try something like this:

```css
.block {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  border:1px solid red;
  text-align:center;
}
.block img {
  height:calc(200px * var(--s,1));
  width:calc(200px * var(--s,1));
  /*You can keep only one of the above and the other will be auto*/
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
   <img src="https://lorempixel.com/200/200/">
   <div>img name</div>
</div>

<div class="block">
   <img src="https://lorempixel.com/200/200/" style="--s:0.5">
   <div>img name</div>
</div>

<div class="block">
   <img src="https://lorempixel.com/200/200/" style="--s:0.2">
   <div>img name</div>
</div>
```

You can also do it in this way:

```css
.block {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  border:1px solid red;
  text-align:center;
}
.block img {
  width:calc(100% * var(--s,1));
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
   <img src="https://lorempixel.com/200/200/">
   <div>img name</div>
</div>

<div class="block">
   <img src="https://lorempixel.com/200/200/" style="--s:0.5">
   <div>img name</div>
</div>

<div class="block">
   <img src="https://lorempixel.com/200/200/" style="--s:0.2">
   <div>img name</div>
</div>
```